# Configuring wait time of SOAP request node and SOAP input node in IIB

Tags: soap, ibm-integration-bus

I am using IIB V10.Can we increase the max client wait time of SOAP input node more than 180 seconds(default) in IIB. Also, can we configure the request time out of SOAP request node from 120 seconds(default) to a higher number?

Answer (score 0):

The IIB documentation describe these timeouts in detail here:

- `maxClientWaitTime` of [SOAP Input](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56170_.html) node.
- `requestTimeout` of [SOAP Request](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56190_.html) node.

You can configure these values either directly in the flow as properties of the nodes or via BAR overrides before the deployment.

There is also general chapter called [Configuring message flows to process timeouts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc43720_.html?pos=2) which describes the timeout handling of these synchronous nodes.

Comment: I saw that.MY doubt whether it is advisable to increase the timouts from default numbers.

Comment: Of course you can change the timeout as needed. Just remember that when you increase the timeouts your thread handling the request is blocked for longer time and can not handle other requests.